# Call MiSys Equation API from BizTalk

Tags: integration, biztalk, ibm-midrange

How can I call MiSys Equation API from BizTalk or .NET? 
Equation is a banking system hosted on ISeries AS/400 server. 
is the Host Integration server way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we need to use IBM iSeries Access for window for this.
just wrote a blog post on this

http://usmanshaheen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/invoke-misys-equation-api-from-net/

Answer (score 0):

You need to Call the API Program from .net,Java,VB Program thru Remote call or using MQ .

How you are looking for ?

Comment: I'm looking into HIS 2009. will update here once I found the exact one